# express parameters and api endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an express api endpoints for different purpose, but a single one is returning results for all the endpoints.
example.
`api/:id`   returns id.
`api/:id?region=east`    returns {region: "east"}
I know in the first case we use `req.params`, second case  `req.query`.
My problem is for both calls, the results  are from first case only.
How can I resolve this?

sample `code app.js file`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use('/api', require(./server/user.js));

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port} `));
```

```
#user.js file

const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

//endpoint api/10
//ie 10 is the id
router.get('/:id', (req,res) =>{
   let id = req.params;
  return res.json(id); 
});

//note the second router should be using query string
//ie api/10?region=east
router.get('/:id', (req,res) =>{
   let id = req.params;
  return res.json(id); 
});
```

My problem is the second api endpoint doesn't work. it executes the first api endpoint.

1 Updates above

Comment: Can you post more code to show a couple the entry point and a few routes?

Comment: @Kose You want to use params and query string within same endpoint.?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please be more explicit and precise.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma yes

Comment: @Kose you can use both `req.params` and `req.query` to access then within the same endpoint.

Comment: @LenJoseph  and Nino , see updated sample code

Answer (score 1):

You can use single route instead of making two different routes, you will just need to check for query string in the request as shown below.

```
router.get('/:id', (req,res) =>{
   let id = req.params;
   let region;
   if(req.query){
     region = req.query.region;
   }
   return res.json(id); 
});
```